# Magento 2 : Separate Magento Stores

Tags: magento2.4, stores, remove

I have two stores on one magento dashboard. One of the stores is being taken over by another company. Is it possible to remove one store and transfer it to it's own magento platform?
Thanks

Comment: You can remove from current store, but transfer to another magento it some what needed extra things to do.

Answer (score 0):

- Take the backup of your current Magento and create a replica of it on the new server.
- Assign temporary URLs to both stores in the new instance (just to test everything is working properly)

Now you have 2 servers each running stores.

**On Server 1:**

- Remove all related configuration of store 2 from the server 1.
- Remove store 2 (which has been taken over by another company) from the server 1.

**On Server 2:**

- Remove all related configuration of store 1 from the server 2.
- Remove store 1 (which has been taken over by another company) from the server 2.

Everything is done now.

Do a full reindex on both servers and start testing.